# Очистка swap в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap

Перенес swap на другой раздел. В /etc/fstab указал новый uid. Теперь во время работы системы если происходит обращение к swap, то он не очищается. Наблюдаю за загрузкой в htop. При повышении нагрузки swap используется, при снижении нагрузки не очищается. До переезда такого не было. Меня беспокоит нормальность такого поведения, может ли это означать, что swap некорректно работает?

Comment: аналогичное поведение
хотя настраивал swap при установке ubuntu 15.10

Comment: А разве система должна очищать своп? ей что, делать больше чего нет? А вот когда там не будет хватать места, то она сама и подчистит, если есть что. А вот если нет... значит нужно  искать, где утечка памяти в приложениях.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте в крон очистку свап (под супер-пользователем):

```
swapoff -a && swapon -a
```

У меня на сервере тоже как то не очень освобождается swap. Растёт постепенно. Но мне это пока не мешает. Очень редко ручками очищаю.